# Resources not found in OSGI and JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, junit4

I have an OSGI bundle A that hosts a number of resources, e.g:

```
resouces/myfile.txt
```

In the bundle there is a class called ResourceLoader, which contains the following code:

```
    public boolean registerProviders(String name) {
        ClassLoader loader = BundleA.class.getClassLoader();
        URL url = loader.getResource(name);
        return ( url != null );
    }
```

I also have a Fragment Bundle TestA that provides the unit tests for bundle A. One of the tests, `registerProvidersTest`,  calls the `registerProviders` method described above. When I try to run `registerProvidersTest` as a JUnit Test from the launcher, the resources are not found. I have verified that the class loader indeeds points to a class of bundle A, and the problem only seems to occur when running a JUNit test; accessing the `registerProviders` method from another bundle works fine.

As far as I can tell, the problem must be in JUnit (in an OSGI environment). I have tried JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 test, using Eclipse version: 2020-09 (4.17.0). I have also experimented with various variations on the name. I'm pretty sure I am not the only one to have run into this issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you running JUnit in an OSGi environment? Also, what is `ClassFactory`?

Comment: Hi Neil, I am running the default Eclipse launch option for JUnit tests Run as... Junit Test. The ClassFactory is the Class that I rewrote to 'Bundle A' in the question. I should have changed that as well. The ClassFactory is in the same bundle a the resources I am trying to retrieve.

Comment: Launching with "Run As > JUnit Test" from Eclipse does not create an OSGi runtime.

Comment: Not sure what kind of project you are working with but if you are working with plugin creation then  you have to run your test as run as->plugin test.  Run as unit test will not initialise and create the osgi runtime.